# Submit a python job to spark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I'm trying to submit a job written in python to spark.

First I'm going to explain my setup, I installed a single node of spark 2.3.0 on a performing windows server (40 cores and 1TB or RAM), of course the goal will be later to create a cluster of less powerfull nodes, but for now I'm testing everything there :)

My first test consists on taking a set of tabular CSV files (40-100GB each), split them and then save the splitted result somewhere else.

I've been making my prototype on a `jupyter notebook` using `pyspark` (which creates automatically a sparkContext.

Now, I want to create a spark_test.py script, containing the body of my prototype in the main, which I'm planning to send to the spark-submit.

The thing is that seems like the processing part of my script is not working at all. Here you have the body of my script:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def main():
    # Create spark context
    spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName('GMK_SPLIT_TEST')
    print('\nspark configuration: \n%s\n' % spark_conf.toDebugString())
    sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)

    # Variables definition
    partitionings_number = 40
    file_1 = r'D:\path\to\my\csv\file.csv'
    output_path = r'D:\output\path'

    # Processing 1
    rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000))
    print(rdd.mean())

    # Processing 2
    sdf = spark.read.option('header','true').csv(file_1, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
    sdf_2 = sdf.repartition(partitionings_number, 'Zone[3-2]')
    sdf_2.write.saveAsTable('CSVBuckets', format='csv', sep=';', mode='overwrite', path=output_path, header='True')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Now here is where I have more doubts. Does spark-submit will try to connect to an already running instance of spark or it will initialize one by itself? 
I tried:

```
spark-submit --master local[20] --driver-memory 30g
```

The above command seems to work if for the Processing 1, but no for the Processing 2

```
spark-submit --master spark:\\127.0.0.1:7077 --driver-memory 30g
```

The above command raises an exception of spark contex initialization. Is it because I don't have any spark instance running?

How so I have to pass my file_1 with my python job in order to have do the processing 2? I tried --files without success.

Thank for your time guys!

Comment: Your second spark submit command is run against a standalone cluster running with a master on localhost. Have you installed and started a standalone cluster?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I've a single node installed which when using whit `pyspark` I initialize as master.